# CartThrob Product - Simple FT not rendering

Tags: ee2, cartthrob, fieldtype

I recently upgraded CartThrob 2.61 to v 2.71 on my development server.

After updating modules, everything seems to work fine except for when I try to render a **CartThrob Price - Simple** fieldtype in my templates.

Using the following test example on a development page, the page loads continuously before timing out. So I have no use of the template debugger or the profiler to help me out. There are no PHP errors or Apache errors for me to trace either.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="10"}
    {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form entry_id="{entry_id}" 
    }
        Title: {title} <br/>
        Price: £{product_price} <br/>
    {/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Has anybody come across anything similar? Can anyone give me any tips on how to begin to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had recently installed the **CartThrob Subscriptions** module alongside the new 2.71 **CartThrob Pro** upgrade.

After doing some laborious debugging work, uninstalling and reinstalling the CartThrob module, I discovered that the EE channel assigned to serve as the  Products Channels for the CartThrob Pro module (*Store - Channel*) had been **reassigned** to a new channel created by the installation of **CartThrob Subscriptions** (*Store - Subscriptions*).

Because of this, all my field mappings had been lost. Therefore no values were being assigned to any of the **CartThrob Price - Simple** fieldtypes for my products.

Rather than be informed of this with a notification or even a PHP logged error, I was given nothing. Poor form CartThrob and Vector Media Group.

You just wasted 4 hrs of my time.